# How can I configure Flask-Cache with infinite timeout

Tags: flask, flask-cache

In the Flask-Cache documentation all the examples use a finite timeout.

I'd like to never refresh the cache while the app is running. Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Comment: You can't just set it to a really big number? If you want it cached forever, maybe you should just save it to a file and serve that?

Comment: Both solutions will do, but I was just curious if infinite caching was supported at all

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Flask-Cache uses `werkzeug.contrib.cache` behind the scenes. From the [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/contrib/cache/) it's made clear that

> A timeout of 0 indicates that the cache never expires.

So yes, infinite caching is supported and can be turned on by setting the timeout to zero.

Comment: Here is an example: `cache.set(event, value, timeout=0)`

Comment: Documentation link is broken, here is one for Flask-Caching (not Flask-Cache!): https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does an infinite timeout mean the cache files are never deleted?

Answer (score 8):

There does not seem to be anything listed in the docs. I have used the following and it works fine.

```
     cache = Cache(webapp, config={
         'CACHE_TYPE': 'filesystem',
         'CACHE_DIR': 'cache-dir', 
         'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 922337203685477580,
         'CACHE_THRESHOLD': 922337203685477580
     })
```

That is way more years than you will need to worry about so for all intents and purposes, let's call that infinite.

Comment: As far as `CACHE_THRESHOLD` goes you could set it to e.g. `math.inf` which feels cleaner.

Comment: Big, undefined numbers lead to poor code readability. If I was another dev looking through this code years after it was written, I would have no idea what those numbers mean or how they were generated. Using something more symbolic like `0` or `math.inf` is much better than this.