# Generate a static page from a Jinja template and serve it with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to create a page that once generated will remain static so my server doesn't waste resources regenerating content.  I know about memoizing but was wondering if Flask provides a built-in or different method for this.

Comment: Do you want all pages like this or only a certain page?

Comment: Just a certain page(s), certainly not all of them. The contents of the page can change whenever I restart the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Flask-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/).

Start by creating the `Cache` instance:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cache import Cache
application = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(application, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
```

Notice that the `CACHE_TYPE = 'simple'` uses a python dictionary for caching. Alternatively, you can use `memcached` or `redis` and get greater scalability.
Or, you can use `CACHE_TYPE = 'filesystem'` and cache to the file system.

Then decorate your view functions:

```
@cache.cached(timeout=100000)
def viewfunc():
    return render_template('viewtemplate.html')
```

Comment: See this discussion about ["infinite timeout"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938711/how-can-i-configure-flask-cache-with-infinite-timeout) with Flask-Cache.

Answer (score 6):

`render_template` produces a string.  A string can be saved to a file.  Flask can [serve files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

```
# generate the page at some point
import os
out = render_template('page.html', one=2, cat='>dog')
with open(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'page.html') as f:
    f.write(out)

# serve it some other time
from flask import send_from_directory
return send_from_directory(app.instance_path, 'page.html')
```

This example just puts the file in the [instance folder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#instance-folders) (make sure that exists first) and hard codes the file name.  In your real app I assume you would know where you want to save the files and what you want to call them.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, [Flask-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) will be a better choice, as it handles storing and loading the cached data for you and can save to more efficient backends (or the filesystem still).